# About using this.type in scala

Tags: scala

I defined two classes:

```
class A { def method1 = this }
class B extends A { def method2 = this }

val b = new B
```

Then I checked the type of b.method1:

```
scala> b.method1.getClass
res29: Class[_ <: A] = class B
```

In this case, I cannot use `b.method1.method2`:

```
scala> b.method1.method2
<console>:11: error: value method2 is not a member of A
              b.method1.method2
```

So I have to define A and B like this:

```
class A { def method1: this.type = this } 
class B extends A { def method2: this.type = this } 

val b = new B
```

Now I check the type of `b.method1`:

```
scala> b.method1.getClass
res31: Class[_ <: B] = class B
```

Here `b.method1.method2` works:

```
scala> b.method1.method2
res32: b.type = B@4ff3ac
```

My question here is what does it mean by saying `Class[_ <: A] = class B` and `Class[_ <: B] = class B`? And why does the first doesn't work as `Class[_ <: A] = class B` seems to say that it's also class B?

Comment: `.type` is a singleton type, a special concept in Scala. e.g. `3.type` isn't `Int`, it's `3.type`, a singleton type containing only the number 3. Hard to be sure, but it looks like you think `.type` means something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's split the expression `Class[_ <: A] = class B`. The first part, `Class[_ <: A]` tells you what the compiler knows at compile time, that `b.method1.getClass` returns something of type `Class[_ <: A]`. The second part, `class B` mentions that you have a class `B` as value, but the compiler doesn't know that. That's runtime information.

`this.type` specializes the method for subclasses, where the type inferred from a plain `this` doesn't.